# how to run .sch file in racket environment?

Tags: scheme, racket

0.1 installed. But I did not how to run a .scm file from command line of racket.

I have a scheme code file call code.scm.

And I also a test file call test.scm.

How do I run test.scm in racket? What command do I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
racket -r test.scm
```

If `test.scm` is a module, then instead of `-r` (`--script`), use `-u` (`--require-script`). You can find out more information by running `racket --help`.

Comment: And for R5RS and R6RS you have the wrapper scripts [plt-r5rs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/plt-r5rs.html?q=plt-r5rs) and [plt-r6rs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/Running_Top-Level_Programs.html).

Comment: if i type the racket -r test.scm,it has following message: racket:undefined